# extract database configuration from hibernate.cfg xml file

Tags: xml, regex, bash

The **hibernate.cfg**  contains database configuration such as username,password,dbname and dbhost

```
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://DBHOST:3306/DBNAME?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;tcpKeepAlive=true</property>
    <property name="connection.username">DBUSER</property>
    <property name="connection.password">DBPASS</property>
```

I need a bash script to extract these data.

Comment: What have __you__ tried so far?

Comment: I found xml_grep, but I haven't permission to install new packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), you can use xpath.

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v './/property[starts-with(@name, "connection.")]' hiberate.cfg 2>/dev/null ; echo
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc:mysql://DBHOST:3306/DBNAME?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;tcpKeepAlive=true
DBUSER
DBPASS
$
```

Comment: +1 How refreshing. Not yet another link to [this classic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/383793), but a CLI tool I didn't know.